# how to eliminate robot's parts from lidar data?

Tags: lidar, ros-kinetic, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have turtlebot3 waffle model and lidar in the center.

And I have four vertical rods around lidar

And I have laser data about them.

you see, there is 4 points that indicates these 4 rods.

[image: image description]

So, how can I filter this data in laserscan?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336861/how-to-eliminate-robot%27s-parts-from-lidar-data?/) by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-11-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LeoE](https://answers.ros.org/users/38438/leoe/) on 2019-11-05**:
The simplest way I see would be to just filter scans with ranges below the size of the robot

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-11-05**:
you mean writing a script?

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2019-11-05**:
No need to write script: http://wiki.ros.org/laser_filters

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-11-06**:
ok, I found that hector (slam method) have parameter laser_min_distance. So, I think, it helps to not take into account this points while building map.

but what about gmapping and rtabmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The comment about the laser filters is right if you want something fast.

A common thing many robotics companies do is create robot self filters. This looks at the relative positions of the mesh, or a simplified version of the mesh, and removed laser readings that are internal to it. This is really useful if you don't want to remove things close to the robot but not in the robot.

If you're not too concerned about removing some laser readings just outside the robot but close by, making a simple box or angle filter in the laser filters package is a totally reasonable way to go.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1